# Publish framework in private Cocoapods from CI gitlab

Tags: ios, cocoapods, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab pipeline that builds my framework, uploads the build, creates a podspect.

Right now I wanted a new job that would be able to upload this podspect to a private cocoapods repo.

For that I need to run the following lines of code in the job script

```
pod repo add $MY_COCOAPODS_NAME $MY_COCOAPODS_URL
pod repo push $MY_COCOAPODS_NAME PODSPEC_PATH
```

The problem is that Pipeline runs in VM and I can't get this VM to have the correct configuration to have permissions to access this private repository.

I'm using macOS-tart .
What would be the correct way to configure accesses in this VM